Tabulator and Ajax download only the current table
I am using Tabulator to display the results of an ajax query, and giving the user the ability to download the results to CSV or PDF. All is working fine, except that the download option creates multiple files, seemingly one for every ajax query that the user has submitted (e.g. if they submit 3x queries, a download will be produced for each one). I only want to download the current table.
Ajax function (partial) to create table:
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: actionUrl,
    data: {
        action: 'builder',
        postData: form.serialize()
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(data){     
        var table = new Tabulator("#search_results", {
            data:data,
            fitData:true,
            layout:"fitDataTable",
            columnDefaults: {
                headerSortStartingDir: "desc"
            },
            columns:[

Download function:
document.getElementById("download-pdf").addEventListener("click", function(){
    table.download("pdf", "XXX " + formattedDateStr + ".pdf", {
        orientation:"landscape",
        title:"XXX " + formattedDateStr,
    });
});

I have found one potential solution to separate the table creation to a separate function and use table.destroy(), however before I go about changing my code I'm wondering if there is a simpler solution which I'm missing?
I have read the Tabulator documentation and searched for a possible option. I have found one potential solution mentioned above.

Resolved by changing addEventListener (per the Tabulator documentation) to:
document.getElementById("download-pdf").onclick = function(){
Previously each time the function would run, it would add another event listener, resulting in multiple file downloads.
